# wordpress widget_title filter not working in primary sidebar

Tags: php, html, wordpress, genesis

I have a little problem and I have no clue why this is not working.

I have made small function

```
    add_filter( 'widget_title', 'tbw_html_widget_title', 10 );

   function tbw_html_widget_title( $title ) { //HTML tag opening/closing     brackets

    $title = str_replace( '[', '<', $title );
    $title = str_replace( '[/', '</', $title );
    $title = str_replace( ']', '>', $title );

    return $title;
}
```

On my custom sidebars on the homepage this is working.
See: http://www.cultuurpleintholen.nl/

There is: "EXPOSITIES (meer)" with a link. This is what I want.

Now the strange thing. I have used same code/widget for the primary sidebar and now on the other pages eg: http://www.cultuurpleintholen.nl/subsidies/ there is no "EXPOSITIES (meer)", but only EXPOSITIES. The HTML is stripped.

I use Genesis framework.

Does somebody know why the HTML is stripped?

Comment: there is still 'meer' but it is a dark link. When you hover over it it will become white.

Comment: the 2nd str_replace is useless... The job is done by the first one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from redundancy there is no error in your function.

It is a CSS thing.

This part

```
.sidebar .widget-title a {
    color: #333;
    border: none;
}
```

is taking over. Remove the color setting in your style.css and things will be fine.

Comment: Thank you, i think i was looking with my sunglasses :-)